# elasticsearch クラスタを組んだ時のHA(High Availability)性について。

Tags: linux, centos, elasticsearch

elasticsearchをクラスタ環境で作成したときに下図のような要領でHA性を保ってくれるものかと思ったのですが、どうやら違いました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像続き（１枚の絵に収まりきらなかったのでここから２枚目）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

elasticsearchのクラスタはHA性を保ってくれないのでしょうか？
それとも何か設定ファイルにHA性を保つようなオプションを記載してあげる必要があるのでしょうか？

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教示頂けませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

何か足りない情報等ありましたら追記させて頂きます。

Comment: 図示していただいた動きが理想の動きだったとして、現状ではどう動いているのでしょうか。どの段階から違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: 自動でノード間のシャードのリバランスはもちろんできます。ただし、大量のシャッフリングが発生するため、1台復活したからといって即リバランスする設定にはデフォルトではなっていないと思います。。スイッチの故障なら複数台復同時に復活することもあるわけで、何台のノードが有効なのかわからないでしょう。discovery.* gateway.* あとはnode.*あたりの設定を記載してください。

Comment: Yukiさん
回答ありがとうございます。
どういう動きになっているか動画を撮ってみました。
https://youtu.be/1Y40bnOcWfo

nginxのアクセスログをfluentdを用いてelasticsearchに入れているんですが、この状態になってしまうとfluentdのほうでwarnログが出てしまいます。
Could not push logs to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.86.194.56:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Comment: Kenjiさん
回答ありがとうございます。
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.ymlの設定ファイルは下記の4項目しか入れていないのですが、他に確認するところがありますでしょうか？お手数おかけして申し訳ございませんがご教示頂ければ幸いです。
cluster.name: els-test
network.host: _eth0:ipv4_
node.name: "els01"
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.86.194.56", "10.86.193.157", "10.86.194.95"]

Comment: こちらの要望としましては、3台でクラスタ稼動中ならば最悪2台が死んでもelasticsearchにデータを入れられるような状態にさせたいのですが、それは不可能でしょうか？

Comment: 僕は7ノードのElasticsearchを運用していますがバージョンがちょっと古い(1.4)ので、最新の2.2をVM3つに入れて同じ条件で実験してみました。結果はあっさりリバランスされてシャードが3台のノードに分散されました。ドキュメントの数によりリバランスまで結構時間がかかります。ログを見ると経過が分かると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
自分の場合は2台落とすときのタイミングが早すぎたのでしょうか？
もう少し試してみようと思います。

さすがにほぼ2台同時に落ちた場合はどうしようもないですよね。